# How to use Notify js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, notifications

I'm trying to give a success notification from my jQuery to the client...... this is how my script looks like.....

```
$('#submit').click(function () {

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../Home/Index",
        data: $('#form').serialize(),
        success: function(data){
                $('#message').notify("Access Granted");
        },
        error:function(){
            alert("Error!!!!");
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

But the notify part wont work in this..... it wont even give me an error... nothing happens.........
I have included the jQuery and Notifyjs scripts as well in my page....

Comment: are you sure its going to the success part, place a `console.log()` or alert() in success, and get back

Comment: yes it goes to the success part

Comment: have you tried `$.notify("Hello World");` as per their page. It adds to the `document`. check and see, is container with id `message` is visible